# How to work through WebDriver Manager issue?

Tags: automation, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using a Asus Windows 64.  I have pycharm installed.  I keep getting the following error.

DM] - ====== WebDriver manager ======

Started scenario:  User Signin

[WDM] - Current google-chrome version is 120.0.6099
[WDM] - Get LATEST chromedriver version for 120.0.6099 google-chrome
HOOK-ERROR in before_scenario: ValueError: There is no such driver by url https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE_120.0.6099
HOOK-ERROR in after_scenario: AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'driver'

I've tried updating my chrome driver but I'm not to get it to work.